Why does spline animation stop when getting out of the screen
Basically my problem seems very simple but I can't find an answer, I have multiple structs and they just have a spline.design. These designs that I made have some animations plus they allow to zoom in and out and rotate, etc. It is like the following, very simple:
struct Train: View {
    var body: some View {
        SplineView(sceneFileURL: URL(string: "//my url")!)
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

Now I add it in my main page:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Train()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            CottonGin()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            Boat()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always)) // Enables swiping with pagination
        .ignoresSafeArea() // Ensures the views occupy the entire screen
    }
}

Basically this works fine for the first time I visit any of the pages and go to another page, then if I return to the page(like swipe to the next page and then come back) the spline designs stop working.
I then tried to add to each struct a .id(UUID()) but that did not work, I don't know why, so:
struct Train: View {
    var body: some View {
        SplineView(sceneFileURL: URL(string: "//my url")!)
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            .id(UUID())
    }
}

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Note that .id(UUID()) will create a new id each time the view is redrawn.

will that refresh the page? Cause maybe its getting stuck and i need to do new instace
